# Custom marshalling, unstandard form

Tags: java, rest, jersey, marshalling, unmarshalling

I know that there are Java libraries that convert XML strings into objects. Also, Jersey contains ways of consuming certain datatypes.

My problem is that I have a String that represents an object (like the XML string, but not XML), and I was curious if there was an easy way to make a custom marshaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JAXB for marshalling, try writing an [XmlAdapter](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) (despite the name, it can marshal to/from `String`).

If you're using Jackson, they have a [HOWTO for writing custom serializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

Some additional details of what tools and frameworks you're already using would help generate more specific answers.

Comment: Right now, the data comes in as a multi-valued map. The equivalent of "tags" are the keys, while the root level elements are the "values". I am using tomcat6 with Jersey as the servlet.

Comment: Also, I was just kind of parsing the String and manually creating java objects.

Comment: If the String is your custom "not quite XML" format, you will still need to manually parse the String to create a Java object.  You can automate this using a parser/lexer framework but you'll still have to write the grammar and related methods to handle the edge cases of your format.

If you can switch from a custom format to a String format that is already understood (e.g. YAML, JSON, even well-formed XML) then your job will be easier.

But if you can't, what I was saying above is that you can write a serializer/adapter so that the parsing and conversion code is in only one spot.

Comment: Yeah, this was the corret route. I had to make an algorithm to convert my input into XML then use STAX. I was hoping for a more elegant solution in terms of the infrastructure available, but this works! Thanks for the help.